# Netgear CM1150V modem has unknown blinking light pattern, no connection to internet

Tags: networking, netgear-router

My Netgear CM1150V cable modem stopped working this afternoon. The light pattern on the front shows all four network port lights as solid amber. All the other lights including power, upstream, downstream, internet, phone 1,and phone 2 are blinking green in unison at about a two second interval. There is no connectivity to the internet.

I have power cycled device. I have performed a factory reset and the problem remains. The light pattern is unchanged.

I'm hoping someone has some ideas.

Comment: Please contact Xfinity.

Comment: @changanauto - I contacted them last night and a tech will be here this afternoon. I'm trying to diagnose it without having to pay them a fee to examine my equipment. I do have active TV to the house, so I know there is a signal present. I'll wait and see what the guy says.